# Churn/ survival prediction - Cox Regression and Recursive Factors

Tags: survival, cox-model, churn

I'm trying to come up with a straightforward subscription churn (survival) model and - in broad strokes - see the most important factors by size.

I know this can be a loaded topic.

It looks like doing some exploratory analysis using a Cox Survival Regression might be useful.

However, conceptually, I'm trying to understand measuring the impact of certain 'recursive' factors.

For instance - if were trying to assess the impact of Customer Ratings on Churn Risk. Intuitively, one might think a better rating/ experience would be correlated, weakly or strongly, with survival/ not churning.

However, it turns out even making a contact at all suggests baseline interest (and age) -- and then only a % even bothers to rate (suggesting even more baseline interest and age).

Hence a customer even rating the business a "0" is likely to survive much longer than a customer who never filled out a survey/ contacted us at all. Is this something that can be accounted for in a Cox Regression? Trying to think of the right way of thinking about this.

Comment: To the question in your last paragraph: yes, I think that could be accounted for in the model with a time-varying binary variable that tracks whether customer i has contacted the company at all at any point from 0 to t.